How to ensure initialization of static variables without explicitly including the header file
Considering the following example: A class named ObjectFactory is defined to manage the creation of several classes. These managed classes should be registered with the factory so that we can create the corresponding instances.
Since there are hundreds of managed classes, to simplify the registration process I introduce the following class:
template<typename T>
class ObjectRegistrar {
public:
  ObjectRegistrar() {
    ObjectFactory::Instance()->Register(CLASS_NAMES(T), []() { return std::make_unique<T>(); });
  }
};

In each managed class, for example A:
class A {
private:
  inline static ObjectRegistrar<A> _registrar{};
};

a static member variable is added. At the beginning of the program, all static variables will be initialized, thus registering class A with the ObjectFactory. However, when some managed classes are not explicitly included (despite being compiled, as indicated by the compiler output), the static variable is not initialized. I suspect it is removed by the linker since the static variable is never used.
What can I do to ensure that all the static variables are initialized correctly without explicitly including all the managed classes? Including all managed classes in one place makes the code overly coupled.

Does adding volatile  change anything in the behavior you observe ? Not saying its the way to go here, just to test your assumption reg. optimization.

For class A to be able to use ObjectRegistrar it must include the header-file where ObjectRegistrar is defined. And for any code to be able to use A it needs to include the header-file where A is defined. Which means that all needed header files should have been included. Perhaps you should try to create a [mre] to show us? The problem could be somewhere else?

@nick Tried adding volatile, it not works.

@Someprogrammerdude If A.h is explictly included (in main.cpp for example), then everything works as expected. However, I have hundreds of manged classes like A, including all of them will make the code ugly and overly coupled.

@WoodyHuang We pay for what we use. So including header for the corresponding class if its definition is needed seems fine to me.

You shouldn't include all the header files everywhere (or even in a single source file). But to use each of the "managed" classes, its actual header file needs to be included in at least one source file. Otherwise you just won't be able to use the class (like for example call any of its member functions).

Beware of Static Initialization Order Fiasco.

Second try: If you move the initialization of _registrar into the source file, what happens ? (It's in the header right now, right ?)

@nick: I think that even within cpp files, auto-registration is not guaranteed (but all major compilers do it as expected).

@nick I've tried to put the initialization of _registrar into the source file, still having the same problem.
